# How can I get mongo documents with multiple non-exclusive selectors using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to build a single query to return :

- Documents from their IDs (optional)
- Documents matching a text search string (optional)
- The other documents sorted by score and with a count limited by an integer argument

The total limit is the provided one + the length of the documents array IDs of the first condition.

I used to work with meteor where you can return an array of queries cursors. In this case, I am working with a mongoose backend and I am not sure of how to proceed. I assume I need to use `Model.aggregate` and provide my conditions as an array. However, the request fails with the error `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`.

Each of my conditions works fine individually with a regular `find()` query.

Here is my graphQL query resolver, where I can't find what is going wrong:

```js
              async (root, { search, selected = 0, limit = 10 }, { models: { tag } }) => {
               try {
                   let selector = [{}] // {} should return the documents by default if no other condition is set
                   if (selected.length) selector.push({ _id: { $in: selected } })
                   if (search && search.length) selector.push({
                       $text: {
                           $search: search,
                           $caseSensitive: false,
                           $diacriticSensitive: false
                       }
                   })

                   const tags = await tag.aggregate(selector).sort('-score').limit(limit + selected.length)

                   return {
                       ok: true,
                       message: "Tags fetched",
                       data: tags
                   }
               } catch (err) { return { ok: false, message: err.message }; }
           }
       ),
```

When I log the selector with all the arguments set, it returns an array of the following form:

```js
[
  {},
  { _id: { '$in': [Array] } },
  {
    '$text': {
      '$search': 'test',
      '$caseSensitive': false,
      '$diacriticSensitive': false
    }
  }
]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Based on @Ashh answer, with an additional `$or` operator, the full agregator variable look like this:

```
   {
    '$match': {
      '$or': {
        _id: {
          '$in': [ '5e39745e0ac14b1731a779a3', '5e39745d0ac14b1731a76984' ]
        },
        '$text': {
          '$search': 'test',
          '$caseSensitive': false,
          '$diacriticSensitive': false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { '$sort': { score: -1 } },
  { limit: 12 }
```

I still get the "Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators" error, and I don't see where, if the `$text` argument is not present, I get the default documents by score.

@Ashh, I'll wait for your updated answer to validate it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose `aggregate()` function uses `$match` stage which is equivalent to the `find()` but accepts some stages as array of elements to filter the documents. You can check the example here [`Mongoose Aggregate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate).

And rest is your code fault. It should be

```
async (root, { search, selected = 0, limit = 10 }, { models: { tag } }) => {
  try {
    const aggregate = []
    let selector = { $match: { }};
    aggregate.push(selector)
    if (selected.length) {
      aggregate[0].$match['$or'] = [];
      aggregate[0].$match.$or.push({ _id: { $in: selected }});
    }
    if (search && search.length) {
      aggregate[0].$match['$or'] = aggregate[0].$match['$or'] ? aggregate[0].$match['$or'] : []
      aggregate[0].$match.$or.push({ $text: {
        $search: search,
        $caseSensitive: false,
        $diacriticSensitive: false
      }})
    }
    aggregate.push({ $sort: { score: - 1 }})
    aggregate.push({ $limit: limit })
    const tags = await tag.aggregate(aggregate)
    return {
      ok: true,
      message: "Tags fetched",
      data: tags
    };
  } catch (err) {
    return { ok: false, message: err.message };
  }
};
```